# How does the approximate Hessian update in LBFGS work?

Tags: optimization, derivative, hessian

Looking at the wikipedia page for BFGS... [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm)

It looks like a rearranging of Newton's method, but I can't really explain why the update to the approximate Hessian would be given by the following line...

$$
B_{k+1}(\mathbf{x}_{k+1} - \mathbf{x}_k) = \nabla f(\mathbf{x}_{k+1}) - \nabla f(\mathbf{x}_{k})
$$

I don't see why simply subtracting the derivative from the derivative at the updated function evaluation would give an approximation of the Hessian. Shouldn't there be a denominator to normalize the difference by something in order to be precise, such as in the [simple and traditional derivative calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) which dvides by $h$?

Answer (score 1):

The Wiki page goes on:

---

3. Set $\mathbf{s}_{k}=\alpha_{k} \mathbf{p}_{k}$ and update $\mathbf{x}_{k+1}=\mathbf{x}_{k}+\mathbf{s}_{k}$
4. $\mathbf{y}_{k}=\nabla f\left(\mathbf{x}_{k+1}\right)-\nabla f\left(\mathbf{x}_{k}\right)$
5. $B_{k+1}=B_{k}+\frac{\mathbf{y}_{k} \mathbf{y}_{k}^{\mathrm{T}}}{\mathbf{y}_{k}^{\mathrm{T}} \mathbf{s}_{k}}-\frac{B_{k} \mathbf{s}_{k} \mathbf{s}_{k}^{\mathrm{T}} B_{k}^{\mathrm{T}}}{\mathbf{s}_{k}^{\mathrm{T}} B_{k} \mathbf{s}_{k}}$

---

where $\alpha_k$ is a step size.  So both $y_k$ and $s_k$ include a step size. The two update bits of step 5 both have two $\alpha$s in the numerator and two in the denominator (via $y_k$ or $s_k$)